# How to sort by type before sorting by property

Tags: java, comparator

I am trying to sort by type then property. I'll explain better using an example:

Let's say that there are 3 types: yellow fruit, red fruit and fruit. of course that the types yellow fruit and red fruit have inherited properties from fruit. Under yellow fruit, there is banana and lemon. Under red fruit, there is apple and strawberries. Under fruit, there is watermelon and orange.

When sorted the list should look like this:

Orange, Watermelon, banana, lemon, apple, strawberries

The list is sorted first by types which is fruit then yellow fruit then red fruit. Then in each type, the objects are then sorted by alphabetical order.

This is what I have so far for sorting the alphabetical order within each type but I have no idea how to sort the types. I have getters in other parts of the code.

```
    public static Comparator<Fruit> FRUIT_ORDER = new Comparator<Fruit>() {

        public int compare(Fruit a, Fruit b) {
            
            if (a.getClass() == b.getClass()) {
                String Name1 = a.getFruitName();
                String Name2 = b.getFruitName();
         
                //ascending order
                return Name1.compareTo(Name2);
            } 
            
        }
        
    };
```

Comment: Why do you call `.getClass() `, you already know they are both Fruits?

Comment: @RobOhRob Assuming there are subclasses of `Fruit`, `getClass` will return the `Class` object representing the subclass, not the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that classes Apple and Grapes appropriately subclass Fruit you can do it like this.

```
Comparator<Fruit> FRUIT_ORDER = Comparator
        .comparing((Fruit f) -> f.getClass().getSimpleName())
        .thenComparing(Fruit::getColor);

List<Fruit> f = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(new Apple("Red"), new Apple("Green"),
                new Grapes("Purple"), new Grapes("Green")));

f.sort(FRUIT_ORDER);
System.out.println(f);
```

Could print something like the following (with `toString` override in Fruit class).

```
[Apple Green, Apple Red, Grapes Green, Grapes Purple]
```